# Laravel syntax error, unexpected 'and' (T_LOGICAL_AND), expecting ')'

Tags: php, laravel-4

i am using Laravel4 for my current project.I have a search functionality in my web application.This is my code for search functionality resides in one my controller.php file.

```
public function postBloodSearch(){

        $blood_group = Input::get('blood_group');
        $location = Input::get('location');

        if(empty($blood_group and $location)){

            return Redirect::route('donors')
                    ->with('global','You have to enter both Blood Group and Location');
        }

        $result = Donor::where('blood_group','LIKE','%'.$blood_group.'%')->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')->get();
        return View::make('bloodDonation.blood_array')->with('result',$result);


}
```

You can see,in my code that i have use  php built in **empty** function where actually i am facing
the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'and' (T_LOGICAL_AND), expecting ')'
```

i have tried the following code to solve this problem(just replace the **and** by **&&** )

```
if(empty($blood_group && $location)){.........}
```

now its throwing the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_LOGICAL_AND), expecting ')'
```

**UPDATE:** The same code is working absolutely fine in my local server(Xampp server).But  in my live server(I am using Cpanel),its throwing these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
if(empty($blood_group and $location)){
```

try

```
if(empty($blood_group) and empty($location)){
```

In the above call you are passing a boolean to [`empty function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). The reason for the error is mentioned [`on php docs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) as

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: you can also do `if($blood_group and $location)`